# Corrupt Gzip string due to character encoding

Tags: java, utf-8, character-encoding, gzip

I have some corrupted Gzip log files that I'm trying to restore. The files were transfered to our servers through a Java backed web page. The files have always been sent as plain text, but we recently started to receive log files that were Gzipped. These Gzipped files appear to be corrupted, and are not unzip-able, and the originals have been deleted. I believe this is from the character encoding in the method below.

Is there any way to revert the process to restore the files to their original zipped format? I have the resulting Strings binary array data in a database blob.

Thanks for any help you can give!

```
 private String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) throws IOException {
    /*
     * To convert the InputStream to String we use the
     * Reader.read(char[] buffer) method. We iterate until the
     * Reader return -1 which means there's no more data to
     * read. We use the StringWriter class to produce the string.
     */
    if (is != null) {
        Writer writer = new StringWriter();

        char[] buffer = new char[1024];
        try {
            Reader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
            int n;
            while ((n = reader.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                writer.write(buffer, 0, n);
            }
        } finally {
            is.close();
        }
        return writer.toString();
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Were the files transfered via ftp?  If so, it's possible that ASCII mode was used for the transfer, which works for for plain text, but not for binary files, it can result in several issues; the insertion of extra line feed characters every time there's a carriage return; the removal of line feed characters whenever there's a CR/LF sequence; the changing of the end of file character from either ^D to ^Z or vice versa; and worst of all worlds, if 7 bit ASCII was used, it through away every 8th bit.

Comment: No, the files were transfered via an http POST.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is the method that was used to convert the `InputStream` to a `String`, then your data is almost certainly lost.

The problem is that UTF-8 has quite a few byte sequences that are simply not legal (i.e. they don't represent any value). These sequences will be replaced with the Unicode replacement character.

That character is the same **no matter which** invalid byte sequence was decoded. Therefore the specific information in those bytes is lost.

Answer (score 2):

If that's the code you have you never should have converted to a Reader (or in fact a String). Only preserving as a Stream (or byte array) would avoid corrupting binary files. And once it's read into the string....illegal sequences (and there are many in utf-8) WILL be discarded.

So no, unless you are quite lucky, there is no way to recover the info. You'll have to provide another process where you process the pure stream and insert as a pure BLOB not a CLOB

Comment: Thanks, MJB. We weren't aware that the log files would come in gzipped, so we didn't believe it to be an issue. As of now the code has been altered based on this change, we are just now trying see if we can recover what was lost.